# TCP Client problems

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have few questions (and problems) about the tcp client class.
1. What IP should I give to it constructor, mine or the remote host that I want to connect to? because in MSDN I see that the constructor takes a **local** ip endpoint and I can't understand it.
2. What may be the reason for such statement:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip.Text, port: portNum);
```

to stop the code from running without throwing an exception?

Comment: "In MSDN I see that the constructor takes a local ip endpoint" - [No it doesn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/115ytk56).

Comment: "Initializes a new instance of the TcpClient class and binds it to the specified local endpoint."

Comment: That's a different constructor.  You need to read the documentation for the constructor that you're actually using.

Comment: yes, that's what I didn't understand. one is for local usage and the other for remote usage?

Answer (score 0):

## 1. The IP you should give to the constructor

You should give the IP you want to connect, look about the [IPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.ipaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

## 2. The reason of the statement

Why did you type **`port:`** `portNum` ?
Just write like what is writed in the *[official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/115ytk56)* :

```
//Creates a TCPClient using host name and port.
TcpClient tcpClientB = new TcpClient ("www.contoso.com", 11000);
```

Comment: But the edition is wrong too, because tcp client takes a string and a port number... :\

Comment: That is why I have wrote about IPAdress class ;)

Comment: But the constructor takes a string. I put a string that represent an IP address...

Comment: I can send you the library I've wrote, if you want. In the lib you can connect to an IP using a string ;)

Answer (score 0):

`System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` has four constructors.  The two constructors that seem to be the source of confusion are:

1. TcpClient(IPEndPoint) - *binds it to the specified local endpoint.*
2. TcpClient(String, Int32) - *connects to the specified port on the specified host.*

Constructor #1 is useful if your computer has more than one NIC (e.g. Ethernet and WiFi) and you want to pick which one to use.  If you construct your `TcpClient` instance this way, then you would explicitly call `TcpClient.Connect` to connect the remote host and port number.

Constructor #2 creates the `TcpClient` instance (picking a local endpoint automatically) and immediately connects using the supplied remote host and port.

Comment: thank you. Do you have a suggestion for the 2nd problem?

Comment: If you are receiving a `NullReferenceException`, then `ip` is most likely `null`.  Make sure to supply a valid DNS name (example.com) or IP address in the first argument of the constructor.